# APIException 9011 and 9010 error in Places SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am new to Android Development and I am learning [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro).
My API key for `Maps SDK` is working fine and I am able to see Map on my screen with a marker.
But the problem is, I am not able to use the `Place Autocomplete` service and facing the following two errors:

1. APIException code 9011
2. APIException code 9010

Here my `Places SDK` is not working though I have enabled it while creating API Key. I have searched about these two errors but yet I am unable to find the reason for the above-mentioned errors. Sorry for using bad English, please tell me the reason why it's happening with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the errors you are getting:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-over_query_limit

and

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-request_denied

Make sure you are using the newest Places SDK client and that you are have enabled the Places API.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: Can we use Places SDK without registring Credit card because someone told me that one has to register through his/her credit card in order to use Places SDK?

Comment: You do have to use a credit card because you can't use the API without a valid billing account.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these above mentioned `APIException codes` at [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesStatusCodes). After that Ensure that your `Places SDK` is turned on. But `places SDK` will only work if you have attached your credit card to the `Google Maps account`. that's all.

Comment: Yeah! in my case the credit card was not linked with my account.